# How to keep track of how many seconds I moved forward in a game without using time.sleep?

Tags: python

```
def pathing(shape,size):
target = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\wow bot\references\target.png'),
                                  region=(0, 0, 1024, 768), confidence=.7)
target2 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\wow bot\references\target2.png'),
                                   region=(0, 0, 1024, 768), confidence=.7)
target3 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.expanduser(r'~\Desktop\wow bot\references\target3.png'),
                                   region=(0, 0, 1024, 768), confidence=.7)
distance_moved=[]
seconds_moved=0
if shape=='triangle':
    if target is None and target2 is None and target3 is None:
        pyautogui.keyDown("w")
        distance_moved.append(seconds_moved+1)
        seconds_moved+=1
```

I have the code above to keep track seconds moved, and append it to the list distance_moved[]. However the problem with this is that It doesn't add +1 to seconds moved every 1 second. Is it possible to cause it to add the +1 after every second, but without using time.sleep?

Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `time.time`
Example:

```
import time 
start = time.time()
while True:
    now = time.time()
    print(f"{now - start} second(s) have passed")
```

So in your case:

```
if now - start > 1:
    distance_moved.append(seconds_moved+1)
```

If you want it to keep happening every one second, you can reset the timer like this:

```
if now - start > 1:
    distance_moved.append(seconds_moved+1)
    start = now
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you! time.time returns an error; ' TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method' '. However, time.monotonic worked perfectly. It should be okay to replace time.time with time.monotonic right? Thank you again!! And then to count how many seconds have passed in the end, i can just use len(distance_moved) and the len = seconds moved?

Comment: The error sounds like you did `time.time` as opposed to `time.time()`. You forgot the bracket.

Comment: OH! sorry!!! you're correct I did do time.time instead of time.time(). With the brackets it worked, thank you again!